# How to add training costs to the variables of a model?

Tags: machine-learning, r, statistics, training

I am dealing with the Breast Cancer dataset and I want to include costs to the variables, trying to minimize the training costs and maximizing the accuracy. The costs for each variable are as follows

`testscosts<-c(2,4,3,1,5,3,2,4,2,0)`

The first position of the array corresponds to the first attribute, CL.thickness, the second to Cell.size..

How can I include these costs in a model?

I'm working with R.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Your question is not very clear: what are these costs? Are these the costs of obtaining a value for these variables? So ideally the model should use only a subset of these variables? A classification model must have a fixed set of variables, so the only way to do that would with feature selection.

Comment: What does a cost of 0 (the last one) mean? In what way are those costs factored in the loss function?